# jquery fancybox firefox dimensions issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox to show an overlay video on my website. The following jquery code works fine in Chrome but in Firefox, the video is diminished and the dimensions of the container holding the video are diminished. Following is jquery code

```
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe',
    'width': 800,
    'height': 580,
    'autoDimensions':   false,
    helpers     : {
         media: true
    }
});
```

Below are images from chrome and firefox

[image: Chrome image]

[image: firefox image]

Any help ins this aspect will be appreciated.

Comment: @JFK that doesn't work.

Comment: @JFK that did not help either

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `type : "iframe"` you may not need to use the `media helpers` (which actually moves the content inside an `iframe`).

Also, if you want fancybox to keep fixed dimensions, you would need to add `fitToView: false`, otherwise fancybox will be resized to fit in the view port for smaller screens.

Additionally, you may need to disable `iframe preload` to avoid some known issues when the content is not completely loaded (browsers may process the size calculation differently)

so this code should do the trick in Firefox, Chrome and even in IE7+ :

```
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    width: 800,
    height: 580,
    // add
    fitToView: false,
    iframe : {
      preload : false
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this man...it's not helping at all! I dont know where I am going wrong!

Comment: It's a client site and cannot share the link on a public forum. Can I email you or something? I also see that you are actively replying on the google forum for fancybox. So if I can email you anyway....I am ready for that.

Comment: I figured it out....there was a problem with the fancybox-inner class. I fixed it and now it works fine.

Comment: Hi Ash, could you elaborate on what the problem was please?

Comment: @danielblythe : the issue was fixed disabling iframe preload https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fancybox/IPFVhwG9AHc

Comment: What a beauty! After spending countless hours over this, I looked at a solution which got 0 upvotes, tried it, complied it ..... manager walks up to me and says "how's it going" ... compile compile ... completed ... "yea found a fix" .. browser refresh ... "and it works!!!!" BAM!!!