# Fancybox size/reposition issue after installing IE10

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am experiencing a problem with a login/register Iframe loaded within a fancbox. The Iframe worked perfectly in all versions of IE(9,8,7) before I upgraded to IE10. Now I have reports that anyone that tries to view this Iframe/Fancybox using IE10 now has a problem.

The problem is that the size of the Fancybox is too small and doesn't size to the size of the Iframe. So you end up with this:

[image: IE10 Fancybox/Iframe problem]

FYI: Some developers that have tried to solve the problem think it is something to do with the 'Only secure contet is displayed'.

This is how the files for Fancybox are loaded along with jQuery:
(Some of it may be irrelevant, but that how is how Fancybox is setup on the page it is used)

If you would like to test the problem yourself please follow these steps:

Go here: http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/home
Hover over the "Your Business" main navvigation tab
Click any link under "Channel Partners" on the far right and you'll be take to a page whch opens a Login/Register lightbox that in IE10 no longer displays properly.

FYI also if you have IE10 installed and use developer tools to access the page using IE9,8,7 standards then the fancybox/Iframe doesn't work like you think it might. Seemed a bit strange to me.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue please?

```
    head.js({jquery: "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"});
head.ready("jquery", function() {
    head.js({less : "/pro/assets/script/lib/less-1.1.5.min.js"})
            .js({main: "/pro/assets/script/jquery-main.js"})
            .js({mousewheel : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"})
            .js({validation : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery.validate.min.js"})
            .js({carousel : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"})
            .js({ui : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"})
            .js({isotope : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery-isotope-min.js"})
            .js({lightbox : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"})
            .js({scrollpane : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"})
            .js({autocomplete : "/pro/assets/script/lib/jquery.autocomplete-min.js"})
            .js({eloqua : "/pro/assets/script/debug-eloqua.js"});

});

head.ready("jquery", function() {
    $("a[class='fancybox.iframe']").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

    head.ready("lightbox", function() {
    $(function() {

        sonypro.popup.init({
            trigger : 'a#updateprofile,a#login,a#generic-fancy-box',
            fancy_options: {
                afterClose : function() {
                    if ($_refreshOnClose) {
                        window.parent.location.reload(true);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        sonypro.popup.init({
            trigger : 'a#change-country,a#image-gallery,a#ezone'
        });

        sonypro.popup.init({
            trigger : 'a#restricted-attachment',
            fancy_options: {
                afterClose : function() {
                    if (!$_refreshOnClose && $_goHomeOnClose) {
                        var pattern = /sony\./g;
                        var referrer = window.parent.document.referrer.split("/");
                        domainName = referrer[2];
                        if (pattern.test(domainName)) {
                            window.parent.location.href = window.parent.document.referrer;
                        } else {
                            window.parent.location.href = "http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/home";
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($_refreshOnClose) {
                        window.parent.location.reload(true);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        $('#popupRequestLink').fancybox({
            afterClose : function() {
                if ($_refreshOnClose) {
                    window.parent.location.reload(true);
                }

            },
            beforeShow: function() {
                if ($.browser.msie)
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                else
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').css('margin-top', '-99999px');
            },
            afterShow: function () {
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').hide();
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
            },
            beforeLoad: function () {
                $(document.body).append('<iframe id="iframeContentLoader"></iframe>');
                $('#iframeContentLoader').attr('src', $(this).attr('href') + '&oc=false');
                $('#iframeContentLoader').load(function() {
                    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                    if ($.browser.msie)
                        $('.fancybox-wrap').fadeIn();
                    else
                        $('.fancybox-wrap').css('margin-top', '0');
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            },
            afterLoad: function () {
                $.fancybox.reposition();
                $.fancybox.showLoading();
            },
            helpers   : {
                overlay : {
                    closeClick: true
                }
            }
        }).click();

        $('#restricted').fancybox({
            afterClose : function() {
                if (!$_refreshOnClose && $_goHomeOnClose) {
                    var pattern = /sony\./g;
                    var referrer = window.parent.document.referrer.split("/");
                    var currentLocation = window.parent.location.href;
                    var referrerLocation = window.parent.document.referrer;
                    domainName = referrer[2];
                    if (pattern.test(domainName) && referrerLocation != currentLocation) {
                        window.parent.location.href = window.parent.document.referrer;
                    } else {
                        window.parent.location.href = "http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/home";
                    }
                }
                else if ($_refreshOnClose) {
                    window.parent.location.reload(true);
                }

            },
            beforeShow: function() {
                if ($.browser.msie)
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                else
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').css('margin-top', '-99999px');
            },
            afterShow: function () {
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').hide();
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
            },
            beforeLoad: function () {
                $(document.body).append('<iframe id="iframeContentLoader" style="position:fixed;z-index:-1;top:-99999px;"></iframe>');
                $('#iframeContentLoader').attr('src', $(this).attr('href') + '&oc=false');
                $('#iframeContentLoader').load(function() {
                    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                    if ($.browser.msie)
                        $('.fancybox-wrap').fadeIn();
                    else
                        $('.fancybox-wrap').css('margin-top', '0');
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            },
            afterLoad: function () {
                $.fancybox.reposition();
                $.fancybox.showLoading();
            },
            helpers   : {
                overlay : {
                    closeClick: true
                }
            }
        }).click();

    });
});
```

Also another developer made these comments about the new issue:

We see that fancybox:62 has problems. Below code block exists at
fancybox.jsp. (Highlighted line get the error)

```
head.ready(function(){

            $(function(){

                           if(width != null && height != null &&
width != 'null' && height != 'null'){

                    var fancyboxIframe =
parent.parent.$('.fancybox-iframe');

                    fancyboxIframe.width(width);

                    fancyboxIframe.height(height);


parent.parent.$.fancybox.reposition();


                           }

            });



        });
```

Thank you.

We think parent.parent.$('.fancybox-iframe'); gets error and
fancyboxIframe width and height can't be set. Could you please provide
fix for this?

Comment: I think your implementation is a little bit more complicated than it should be. My advice : upgrade to v2.1.4 and use the option `iframe : {preload: false}`. On the other hand, I don't think you need that many callbacks in your script so something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16138104/1055987 should work just fine. BTW, use IE without any compatibility mode and it would be advisable to set the `DOCTYPE` as the very first line of your html document (no preceding spaces or comments)

Comment: Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mXVww/2/show/lite/) with IE10 to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks JFK, its good to see that you have it working in the JSFIDDLE, so hopefully that means my issue can be fixed. Could I just clarify that what you mean by the DOCTYPE comment you made is that we have 21 lines of emtpy code before the DOCTYPE is set? Also regarding your "IE without compatibility mode" comment, do you mean set this meta tag with something to force non-compatibility mode?

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="xxxx?" /> Also, thank you very much for you reply! Greatly appreciated.